# How do I add numbers to each tableview row beginning from 1

Tags: swift, tableview

I have created a TableView with a Prototype Cell with a lot of content in it, multiple labels, 2 pictures and a view which is colored if the row is selected.

What I want to do now, is I want to add a number for each of the rows created so the user can see how many rows there are. I can't use the ID I get from the Database since it is a random mix of characters.

I added an Int variable 'participantID' which starts from one and increments by one with every cell created and writes the value in a label within the prototype cell.

This does exactly what I want, with just one issue: Every time i scroll in the table the ID is incremented. I know that's because of the reuse of the cells however I couldn't find a way to fix this issue.

This is how it looks (particID):

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "tbcCourseParticipant", for: indexPath) as! participantCell
        let partic = participants[indexPath.row]
        cell.lblId?.text = String(particID)
        cell.lblName?.text = partic.name
        cell.lblFirstName?.text = partic.firstName
        cell.lblBirthDate?.text = partic.birthDate
        cell.lblPhoneNr?.text = partic.phoneNr
        cell.lblPrice?.text = String(partic.payed) + "€"
        particID += 1
        return(cell)
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The total number of rows is `participants.count`. The number of *this* row is `indexPath.row+1` (I add 1 because the user will not expect to start counting at zero the way a programmer would do).

So I would say:

```
cell.lblId?.text = String(indexPath.row+1)
```

Or maybe:

```
cell.lblId?.text = String(indexPath.row+1) + " of " + String(participants.count)
```